# Excel Ewa JavaScript - Embed Workbook Stored in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, onedrive

I am trying to dynamically embed a workbook into a  publishing page on my SharePoint 2013 on-prem site using Excel Services ECMA Script. I am trying to use the Ewa.EwaControl.loadEwaAsync method, but it requires a fileID parameter which should represent a file token for a workbook stored in OneDrive/SkyDrive. What would be the fileID if the workbook is stored in SharePoint in a Document Library? Does this method only work for workbooks stored in OneDrive?